# Bootstrap 4 List Group align badge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Hello I have List Group with font icon, text and badge. I want to align badge to the right, but cannot figure out how. In docs there is only one example with justify-content-between, but that justify content between all three elements, I want only badge to go right.

https://jsfiddle.net/matejvrzala/c0u7px6L/

if I put justify-content-between after font icon it does not do anything.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">
    <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <div class="justify-content-between">
        Cras justo odio<span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">14</span>        
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 1: Take the badge outside of the div:

```
<li class="list-group-item active">
  <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <div class="justify-content-between">Cras justo odio</div>
  <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">14</span>
</li>
```

step 2: Display the badge flex and give it a margin-left: auto;

```
.badge {
 display: flex;
 margin-left: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. And justify-content-between is useless to it does not have to be there at all

Comment: actually only margin-left: auto is important part

Answer (score 4):

Try this )

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">
      <div class="user">
        <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Cras justo odio
      </div>
      <span class="badge badge-default badge-pill">14</span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>

.fa {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/c0u7px6L/1/

Comment: I guess your answer is better than the select answer. Thanks.